# Minecraft Launcher won't load?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-launcher

See, this is a strange one. I couldn't find anywhere on the internet with a solution to the problem, they were all similar but different. When I click on the Minecraft launcher, it starts. But it doesn't load. It just stays as a  blank gray window. Like the one you see for a split second when you start the launcher, and then after that the UI loads in. But it never does, it just stays gray:

[image: Screenshot of the launcher.]

Please help. Also sometimes it works, but it's a very small chance and very infuriating.

Comment: At that point I would delete everything minecraf off my computer, and then reinstall from scratch. (Make a backup of any single player world you wanna keep.)

Comment: I do not know how to fix this, but you could try using a lightweight launcher such as https://multimc.org/, which would probably fix it.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your entire screen with the launcher presented?  Additionally, I would [report it as a bug](https://bugs.mojang.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa).

Comment: @TacoタコスI would, but as soon as I tried opening the launcher to send a screenshot, it happened to work. next time I start Minecraft i'll try to screenshot

Comment: @Tacoタコス https://imgur.com/a/B8konBN